# Efficient way to bulk transfer data from one sqlite database to another with haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to move data from one database a to another database b using haskell. I was wondering what the most efficient method of doing this might be for bulk inserts. I have the following code which works but is incredibly slow in comparison to the python code that i write using the same query. Below is the code that i am currently using:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import           Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Text as T
import           Database.SQLite.Simple
import           Database.SQLite.Simple.FromRow
import qualified Data.Time.Clock as CLK
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

type DatabaseName = String

data Pump = Pump 
  { rId :: Int
  , micropump_id :: Int
  , test_id :: Int 
  , signature :: T.Text
  , cycle :: Int
  , dispense :: T.Text
  , timestamp :: CLK.UTCTime
  } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance ToRow Pump where
  toRow (Pump a b c d e f g) = toRow (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) 

instance FromRow Pump where
  fromRow = Pump <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field <*> field


extractPumpsFromDatabase :: DatabaseName -> Query -> IO [Pump]
extractPumpsFromDatabase n q = do
  conn <- open n
  r <- query_ conn (q) :: IO [Pump]
  close conn
  return r

addPumpsToDatabase :: (ToRow r) => DatabaseName -> Query -> [r] -> IO ()
addPumpsToDatabase n q r = do
  conn <- open n
  executeMany conn q r
  putStrLn ("Done: " ++ n) 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- open "databaseA.db"
  execute_ conn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS micropumps (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, micropump_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER, data TEXT, cycle INTEGER, dispense TEXT, timestamp TIMESTAMP)"
  close conn
  newPumps <- extractPumpsFromDatabase "databaseB"
  addPumpsToDatabase "databaseA" "INSERT INTO micropumps (id, micropump_id, test_id, data, cycle, dispense, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" newPumps
```

is it the conversion to and from the Pump type that is taking so long?

Comment: Have you tried streaming it? Ie. does the Python version copy them over one by one or (like your Haskell version) read them all into memory first? (I think)

Comment: I havent tried streaming it yet i will test that approach out. The python version takes the same approach i return an array of tuples and the insert the tuples using the same sql statement as i do above.

Comment: FYI, your `extractPumpsFromDatabase` and `addPumpsToDatabase` functions seem pretty suspect; Why not just take a connection as a parameter instead of opening and closing the same database connection multiple times?

Comment: I am only opening the connection in `extractPumpsFromDatabase` one time during the execution of the program i see though that for `addPumpsToDatabase` i should just pass the Connection from the original open function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a glance: You're not using a transaction. The python sqlite library does (to my annoyance) automatic transaction management, but in your case it's probably what's causing the main part of the speed difference. Try this instead:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- open "databaseA.db"
  execute_ conn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS micropumps (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, micropump_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER, data TEXT, cycle INTEGER, dispense TEXT, timestamp TIMESTAMP)"
  close conn
  newPumps <- extractPumpsFromDatabase "databaseB"
  withTransaction conn $ 
    addPumpsToDatabase
      "databaseA"
      "INSERT INTO micropumps (id, micropump_id, test_id, data, cycle, dispense, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
      newPumps
```

*Edit*: Note that in the above case I'm using `conn` which you've already closed. You really shouldn't be doing that, just keep the connection open and pass it to `addPumpsToDatabase` as a parameter.

Comment: Well that solved the issue. Thanks for the help i didn't realize that was how sqlite3 handled it with python.